# how to create a line break in a loop

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, while-loop

In the code below I would to add a break tag tag after the radio button displays 5 times. I tried few ways but keep getting the entire number of radio button to repeat.

```
foreach ($salary_tbl as $key=>$value) {
    echo "<span class=\"year\">$key</span><input class=\"margin_r36\" type=\"radio\" value='$value' name='salary_tbl' /><br />";
  }
```

this is what I tried

```
for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++) {
 if ($i < 5) {
    foreach ($salary_tbl as $key=>$value) {
     echo "<span class=\"year\">$key</span><input class=\"margin_r36\" type=\"radio\" value='$value' name='salary_tbl' /><br />";
   }
  }
 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($salary_tbl as $key=>$value) {
    if($count == 5) {
         //Apply the line break here
    }
    echo "<span class=\"year\">$key</span><input class=\"margin_r36\" type=\"radio\" value='$value' name='salary_tbl' /><br />";
    $count++;
}
```

or if you want the line break every 5 records then you can slightly change the code to.

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($salary_tbl as $key=>$value) {
    if($count && $count%5 == 0) {
         //This will apply the line break for every five records
    }
    echo "<span class=\"year\">$key</span><input class=\"margin_r36\" type=\"radio\" value='$value' name='salary_tbl' /><br />";
    $count++;
}
```

another suggestion of mine is, instead of using escape character `\` you could simply use it with single quotes and concatenation operator which is much more readable.

for example.

```
echo '<span class="year">' . $key . '</span><input class="margin_r36" type="radio" value="' . $value . '" name="salary_tbl"/><br />';
```

isn't it much more readable now?

Comment: You will have a line break before the first radio button.

Answer (score 1):

```
$n = 0;
foreach ($salary_tbl as $key=>$value) {
    echo "<span class=\"year\">$key</span><input class=\"margin_r36\" type=\"radio\" value='$value' name='salary_tbl' />";
    if($n % 5 == 0){
        echo "<br />";
    }
    $n++;
}
```

Comment: You will have a line break after the first line.

Answer (score 1):

If I am right you want the break repeated every 5 radio buttons. You can use modulus. IF the count is divisible by 0(that is its 5 10 15 20...), then we add a break

```
$count=0;
foreach ($salary_tbl as $key=>$value) {
if($count and $count%5==0) echo "<br/>";
echo "<span class=\"year\">$key</span><input class=\"margin_r36\" type=\"radio\" value='$value' name='salary_tbl' /><br />";
$count++;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($salary_tbl as $key=>$value) {
    if ($i >= 5) {
      // Line break
      $i=0;
    }
    echo "<span class=\"year\">$key</span><input class=\"margin_r36\" type=\"radio\" value='$value' name='salary_tbl' /><br />";
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: you are wrong, the OP is asking about line break. using break will simply exit the code after the condition is met.

Comment: You will have a line break before each line after the fifth.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a break every 5th line you could use modulo:

```
if ($i % 5 == 0) { 
  // line break
}
```